# reduce the complexity of the program

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity

Here is the program to find the pairs that sums up to 3.

For example:

> INPUT : 0,3,5,1,2,4
>   OUTPUT: 0,3,1,2.

That means it should return all the pairs whose sum is equal to 3.

But I want to reduce the time complexity of this program. Right now I am using two nested for loops.

Can anyone suggest a better method to reduce the time complexity.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
   vector<int> v;
   vector<int> r;
   int x;

   cout << "Enter the elements";

   for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
       cin >> x;
       v.push_back(x);
   }

   for(int i = 0 ; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
   {
       for(int j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++)
       {
          if(v[i] + v[j]  == 3)
          {
              r.push_back(v[i]);
              r.push_back(v[j]);
          }
       }
   }

   cout << "\noutput\n";

   for(int i = 0 ; i < r.size(); i++)
   {
       cout<<r[i]<<"\n";
   }

}
```

Comment: As this is working code, it's probably better on __Code Review__: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If all numbers are positive, you can throw away those ones that `> 3` immediately.

Comment: You can sort the vector in O(nlogn) (disregard any that are bigger than 3 if all positive). Then you can find all of the pairs in a sorted loop using 4 binary search algorithms (search for 3, and 0, search for 1 and 2) which is O(logn) each. So overall O(nlogn)

Comment: take over all values <= 3 in a new array, sort this array, manage two indizes, one from the beginning, one from the ending and stepwise find pairs, increase/decrease minIndex,maxIndex as soon as arr[minIndex]+arr[maxIndex]>3;

Comment: Are input numbers positive ? if yes count 0, 1, 2, 3. Else sort your input and iterate from both side: depending of the result sum, increment the small value, or decrease the big value.

Comment: This question is vague. The input and output examples are such that it is unclear if the intent is to find *adjacent* pairs or *any* pairs. Your "correct" output suggests the former, but you're getting answers that think the latter. For example, (0,3),
 (0,2) and (0,1) are *not* greater than three, and though all of those numbers are in the input sequence, only the first is actual present in the "correct" output. We could *guess* as to why, but clarity in the question would certainly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do two preparation steps; First, eliminate all numbers > 3, as they will not be part of any valid pair. This reduces the complexity of the second step. Second, sort the remaining numbers such that a single walk through can then find all the results.

The walk through approaches the pairs from both ends of the sorted array; if a pair is found, both bounds can be narrowed down; if the current endings do sum up to a value > 3, only one boundary is narrowed.

Runtime complexity is `O(N logN)`, where `N` is the count of elements <= 3; `O(N logN)` basically comes from sorting; the two single walk throughs will not count for large `N`s.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const int N = 3;

    std::vector<int> input{ 0,3,5,1,2,4};
    std::vector<int>v(input.size());
    int t=0;
    for (auto i : input) {
        if (i <= N) {
            v[t++]=i;
        }
    }
    std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());

    long minIdx = 0;
    long maxIdx = v.size()-1;
    while (minIdx < maxIdx) {
        int minv = v[minIdx];
        int maxv = v[maxIdx];
        if (minv+maxv == 3) {
            cout << minv << '+' << maxv << endl;
            minIdx++;maxIdx--;
        }
        else
            minIdx++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First step is only valid if non-negativity of inputs is guaranteed.

Comment: Please don't use macros for constants that are better `const` variables.

Comment: @Andrey Turkin: right. For negative numbers in a set of `values`, the algorithm must be adapted to take over all values `v` where `v + min(values) <= 3`,

Comment: Also this algorithm (as written) will give different results to original if duplicate values are present. E.g. for input {0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3} original algorithm will give 9 pairs and this one will only give 3 pairs.

Comment: Lets say there are `m` numbers out of `n` numbers greater than `key`(the number to find). So first traverse to find all numbers less than `key` that takes `n` iterations. Now we have `(n-m)` elements in array. To sort it would take `(n-m)log(n-m)` and now to find pair `(n-m)`. So in total `n + (n-m)log(n-m) + n-m`. And without the first step it would take `nlog(n)` for sorting and `n` to find the pair. So is  `n + (n-m)log(n-m) + n-m` better than `nlog(n) + n` ?

Comment: Foreach loop is wrong (`i` is a value itself, not index). Something has to be done with `v` array: either use default constructor, `reserve` and `push_back`, or do `resize(t)` after filling in. As it is now, this vector will contain a number of 0s in the end which will be considered as inputs.

Comment: So... another bug for  N=9 and inputs {1, 8, 9}.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for all the combinations between two numbers in **n** elements, more specifically, those that sum up to specific value. Which is a variation of the *subset sum problem*.

To make this happen you could generate all *combinations without repetitions* of the indexes of the vector holding the values. Here is an example of how to do this [recursively](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144172/subset-sum-problem-implementation) and here is an example of how to do it [iteratively](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144210/subset-sum-simple-iterative-implementation), just to get an idea and possibly use it as a benchmark in your case.

Another approaches are [*dynamic programming*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/) and [*backtracking*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backttracking-set-4-subset-sum/).

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this in O(n) with a map.

```
public void printPairs(int[] a, int v)
{
   map<int, int> counts = new map<int, int>();

   for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   {
     if(map.count(a[i]) == 0)
     {
        map[a[i]] = 1;
     }
     else
     {
       map[a[i]] = map[a[i]] + 1;
     }
   }

   map<int, int>::iterator it = map.begin();
   while(it != map.end())
   {
      int v1 = it->second;
      if (map.count(v - v1) > 0)
      {
         // Found pair v, v1 
         //will be found twice (once for v and once for v1)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It will if all of the cells are positive. if O(v/2) is worse than O(n) it would be O(v) though

Comment: Lets say `arr[]={1,2,3,9999,99999,123456,987654}` and want to find all possible pairs of 10000. What would be size of `counts` array?

Comment: @Sniper Edited to use a map so that O(1) insert/lookup solves the issue with V being large. It's also possible to work with negatives.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but works for **negative integers** too... For first, find the smallest number in the `std::vector<int>`, then like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575230/7893951) answer says, remove all elements (or copy the opposite), which are higher than `3 + minimum`. After sorting this `std::vector<int>` iterate through it from both ends with condition shown bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

std::vector<int> findPairs(const std::vector<int>& input, const int sum) {
    int minElem = INT_MAX;
    for(auto lhs = input.begin(), rhs = input.end() - 1; lhs < rhs;
            ++lhs, --rhs) {
        const int elem = (*lhs < *rhs ? *lhs : *rhs);
        if(elem < minElem)
            minElem = elem;
    }

    std::vector<int> temp(input.size());
    const auto tempBegin = temp.begin();
    const auto tempEnd = std::remove_copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
            temp.begin(), [minElem, sum](int elem) {
        return (elem + minElem) > sum;
    });
    std::sort(tempBegin, tempEnd);

    std::vector<int> result;
    auto leftIter = tempBegin;
    auto rightIter = tempEnd - 1;

    while(leftIter < rightIter) {
        if(*leftIter + *rightIter == sum) {
            result.push_back(*leftIter++);
            result.push_back(*rightIter--);
        }
        else {
            if(sum - *leftIter < *rightIter) rightIter--;
            else leftIter++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto pairs = findPairs({ 0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 2, -2, -4, -3 }, 3);
    std::cout << "Pairs: { ";
    for(auto it = pairs.begin(); it != pairs.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << (it == pairs.begin() ? "" : ", ") << *it;
    std::cout << " }" << std::endl;
}
```

The code above will results the following:

```
Pairs: { -4, 7, -2, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2 }
```